# Flutter Dio Client is slow for first couple of requests

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, dio

### Problem

I am using dio for my api calls, when my app starts, I use the same dio instance to launch 6 api requests in parallel (I do not await their futures), the problem is that in the network tab I can see each of the requests by itself takes only about 200ms, but the `Connection established` time of each request is more than 500ms, which result in a total time of about a second for each one, and also several times even many seconds per request.

I understand that there can be a way to reuse the connection to the server, as these requests are to the same base url and same server, but doesn't look like dio is doing that.

What is the way to solve this issue?

here is a screenshot to show what I mean, the orange requests are my api calls, and I expanded the first one so you can see that establishing the connection is what takes most of the time
[image]

Note: - I made sure I am using the same dio instance for all these api calls by printing the hashcode of the `Dio` in them and its the same

- I tested the scenario in all modes on real android and ios devices and the results are the same
- I have pull down to refresh in the app, and it re-calls all these apis (in parallel as well), I noticed that upon reinitiating the requetsts, for the first couple of time, the results are the same, but after refreshing them rapidly many times finally they will each take 200ms

### Relevant Code:

I provide a singleton instance of dio to all my api classes (using injectable package):

```dart
@module
abstract class RegisterModule {
  @singleton
  Dio get myDioClient =>
      myDioClient(logger: logger);
}
```

This is the dio client that I am using:

```dart
/// default timeout for api requests.
const Duration _defaultTimeout = Duration(milliseconds: 1000);

/// Default retry interceptor for handling api requests.
RetryInterceptor _defaultRetryInterceptor({
  required Dio dio,
  required Logger logger,
}) =>
    RetryInterceptor(
      dio: dio,
      logPrint: (message) => log_utils.logMessage(
        runtimeType: '[${dio.runtimeType}]',
        callerName: 'RetryInterceptor',
        logMessage: '[defaultRetryInterceptor]: $message',
        logger: logger,
        level: Level.info,
      ),
      retries: 2,
      retryDelays: const [
        // set delays between retries
        Duration(milliseconds: 500), // wait this much before first retry
        Duration(milliseconds: 1000), // wait this much before second retry
      ],
      retryableExtraStatuses: {401},
    );

Dio myDioClient({
  required Logger logger,
}) {
  final Dio dio = Dio();

  dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

  dio.options.baseUrl = '...';

  dio.interceptors.addAll(
    [
      ApiAuthInterceptor(logger),
      _defaultRetryInterceptor(
        dio: dio,
        logger: logger,
      ),
    ],
  );

  dio.options = dio.options.copyWith(
    connectTimeout: _defaultTimeout,
    receiveTimeout: _defaultTimeout,
    sendTimeout: _defaultTimeout,
  );

  return dio;
}
```